# How to make an INSERT QUERY String using an array of variables

Tags: vb.net, string, insert-into

My code is:

```
For index = 0 To dupColIndx - 1
    expression(index) = dgvINSRT.Rows.Item(i).Cells.Item(index).Value.ToString
Next

Dim strInsrt As String = "INSERT INTO " & _ 
                         dbTbl & _
                         colStr & _
                         Strings.Replace(expression(0), "'", "''", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary) & "','" & _
                         Strings.Replace(expression(1), "'", "''", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary) & "','" & _
                         Strings.Replace(expression(2), "'", "''", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary) & "')"
```

In the code above instead of entering manually expression(0), expression(1), etc. I want the string to be concatenated automatically once I enter the value of 'n' for expression(n).

Thanks.

Comment: How are you utilizing the insert query string? Are you actually sending the command to the database? If so, I would highly recommend using a parameterized (through an `SqlCommand`, `OracleCommand`, etc) to avoid issue with SQL injection (or to catch bad data). Would be easy enough to loop through your array to add each item as a parameter to the command object to send to the database. Need to know what type of command object you are using if this is the case, to write an appropriate code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Join`:

```
For index = 0 To dupColIndx - 1
    expression(index) = dgvINSRT.Rows.Item(i).Cells.Item(index).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "''")
Next

Dim strInsrt As String = "INSERT INTO " & _ 
                     dbTbl & _
                     colStr & _
                     String.Join("','", expression) & "')"
```

Note: If you escape values yourself, it's crucial that you use the correct replacement for the database that you are using, or the query is wide open for SQL injection attacks. The method used here works for SQL Server and Access, but might be wrong for other databases. It's **not** appropriate for MySQL for example, then you also need to escape backslashes.

Comment: The string is returned like this:
`INSERT INTO ['Part Commodity Class$']([Dispatch Commodity],[Dispatch Commodity Temp],[Dispatch Commodity 2]) VALUES ('DispatchCommodity3','DispatchCommodityTemp3','DISPATCHCOMMODITY3','')`

Everything is fine but I am not able to INSERT INTO the dataTable because of the ,'' at the end. Please help in removing this.

Comment: @TheDProgrammer: That means that the array `expression` has one item too much. It should be created using `ReDim expression(dupColIndx - 1)`.

Comment: You Rock!...It worked with `Dim expression(dupColIndx - 1) As String`...Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
If expression.Count >= 1
    Dim strInsrt As String = "INSERT INTO " & dbTbl & colStr

    For i= 0 To expression.Count - 2
        strInsrt &= "'" & Strings.Replace(expression(i), "'", "''", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary) & "',"
    Next i

    strInsrt &= "'" & Strings.Replace(expression(expression.Count - 1), "'", "''", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Binary) & "')"
End If
```

Comment: There is an extra comma and double quote (viz. ,'') at the end which is rendering the INSERT STATEMENT unusable. Please help me correct this:

`INSERT INTO ['Part Commodity Class$']([Dispatch Commodity],[Dispatch Commodity Temp],[Dispatch Commodity 2]) VALUES ('DispatchCommodity2','DispatchCommodityTemp2','DISPATCHCOMMODITY2','')`

Comment: updated my answer, you might have to modify a bit the `colStr` value since I don't know what's in it.